# Mysql Query Optimization [Match Against]

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.6, query-performance

I have tried all the possible option to optimize the query, but no luck.
Query 1:

```
SELECT 
  *, 
  (
    3959 * acos (
      cos(
        radians(51.5073509)
      ) * cos(
        radians(ats_latitude)
      ) * cos(
        radians(ats_longitude) - radians(-0.12775829999998223)
      ) + sin(
        radians(51.5073509)
      ) * sin(
        radians(ats_latitude)
      )
    )
  ) AS `distance`, 
  (
    SELECT 
      `distance`
  ) < 75 AS `in_user_radius` 
FROM 
  table_name 
WHERE 
  `feed` = 'external' 
  AND (
    MATCH (`keywords`) AGAINST (
      'word1 word2 word3*' IN BOOLEAN MODE
    ) 
    OR `title` LIKE '%word1 word2 word3%'
  ) 
  AND `business_area` RLIKE ('word1') 
  AND 1 
HAVING 
  (
    `distance` < 95 
    OR isnull(`distance`)
  ) 
  AND (
    `in_user_radius` = '1' 
    OR isnull(`in_user_radius`)
  )
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT
    *,
    MATCH(`keywords`) AGAINST('word1*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS `score1`,
    MATCH(`title`) AGAINST('"word2"' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AS `score_title_exact`,
    MATCH(`title`) AGAINST('word2' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AS `score_title_phrase`
FROM
    table_name
WHERE
    `jobfeed` = 'external' AND(
        MATCH(`keywords`) AGAINST('word1*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) OR `title` LIKE '%word1%'
    )
ORDER BY
    `nationwide`
DESC
    ,
    `score_title_exact`
DESC
    ,
    `score_title_phrase`
DESC
    ,
    `score1`
DESC
    ,
    `id`
DESC
LIMIT 48, 12
```

Below things I tried to optimize:
1) instead of select * I have specified the specific columns.

Observation: Due MATCH AGAINST condition query is taking too much time to execute.

please suggest some solution to optimize the above queries.

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE!  In order to get any substantial help, please [edit your question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/246846/edit) and add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as that will help better describe the issues you're seeing.  You may also want to include an [`EXPLAIN` plan](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain.html) as that too will help clarify your issue(s).

Answer (score 2):

`MATCH` is not the primary villain in the sluggishness; these are:

- `OR`
- Using `LIKE` / `RLIKE`
- pagination via `OFFSET`
- Most of the above prevent the use of any `INDEX`, hence the query must scan the entire table, thereby being slow for lots of reasons.

Some can be solved in SQL; most require changes to the specifications for the query.

Since the first thing the Optimizer will use is a `FULLTEXT` clause, I will focus on them.

```
        MATCH(`keywords`) AGAINST('word1*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
     OR `title` LIKE '%word1%'
```

This can be simplified (approximately) by:

```
FULLTEXT(keywords, title)   -- add this

MATCH(`keywords`, `title`) AGAINST('word1*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

That should make query2 much faster.

Query1 is pretty hopeless as a starting point.  Can we start with query2 instead?

```
SELECT ...
    FROM ( ...query2... ) AS x
    JOIN table_name AS t2  USING(id)
    WHERE ...
    HAVING ...
    ORDER BY ...  LIMIT ...   -- moved from query2
```

The idea is to

1. combine the tests as discussed above;
2. do the most filtering possible with the least work in the derived table (the subquery);
3. join back to the same table to pick up things left out of the subquery;
4. finish with the rest of the work.